# Can a button change the name of an input text and the action of a form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

My code looks like this :

```
<form method="get">
    <input type="text">

    <input type="submit" formaction="one" value="first">
    <input type="submit" formaction="two" value="second">
</form>
```

What I'm looking for this :

- The input field's name should be "one" if the first button is clicked and "two" if the second button is clicked.
- The form's action should be "first" if the first button is clicked and "second" if the second button is clicked.

So, if the user fills in "foo" in the text box and presses the first button, the browser should go to `http://www.example.com/one?first=foo`. If the user fills in "bar" and presses the second button, the browser should go to `http://www.example.com/two?second=bar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do it, is to use jQuery.

#### Full code :

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="get">
            <input type="text">
            <input type="submit" formaction="one" value="first">
            <input type="submit" formaction="two" value="second">
        </form>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $('input[type=submit]').on('click', function (e) {
                $('input[type=text]').attr('name', $(this).attr('value'));
                $('form').attr('action', $(this).attr('formaction'));
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

#### Note 1 :

You need to make sure your jQuery code is at the bottom of your HTML page, so all of your HTML elements will be loaded when it is executed.

Alternatively, you could also use [**$( document ).ready()**](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                $('input[type=submit]').on('click', function (e) {
                    $('input[type=text]').attr('name', $(this).attr('value'));
                    $('form').attr('action', $(this).attr('formaction'));
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="get">
            <input type="text">
            <input type="submit" formaction="one" value="first">
            <input type="submit" formaction="two" value="second">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

#### Note 2 :

If you don't like to use jQuery, here's how you do the same thing with "vanilla" JavaScript :

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="get">
            <input type="text">
            <input type="submit" formaction="one" value="first">
            <input type="submit" formaction="two" value="second">
        </form>
        <script>
            Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("input[type=submit]")).forEach(function(btn) {
                btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                    document.querySelector("input[type=text]").setAttribute('name', e.target.value);
                    e.target.form.action = e.target.getAttribute('formaction');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you got me wrong. What I'm trying to say by "text's name" is, i want to get `one?first=input` or `two?second=input`

Comment: I think my English isn't enough... i want to get `one?first=the_text_input_from_user` or `two?second=the_text_input_from_user`

Comment: @betseg : I think I know what you mean. I just updated my answer again. Try that code and let me know if that is what you're going for!

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. I tried last one, but doesn't work. It stays as "one?" or "two?" and doesn't have name or input.

Comment: @betseg : If I understand you correctly, the code I gave you should do exactly what you want. If it doesn't, please explain the difference between what you want and what you get. Also, could you set up a demo, so I can debug your code?

Comment: I just paste your code, my code and jQuery links; demo here (not JSFiddle etc, this one really goes to another page): http://betseg.github.io/qwe.html

Comment: @betseg I updated my answer and here is a jQuery solution that like do how you want: https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/0p1xcq7y/2/ ... and if so, let John know so he can update his answer.

Comment: @LGSon : Thanks. However, my solution already worked just fine. He just forgot to put his JS code at the bottom of his HTML (or use `$( document ).ready()`, which means his JS code didn't get executed. I updated my answer with a complete code example (HTML + JS).

Comment: @betseg : You need to do one of two things : (1) put your JS code at the bottom of your HTML code or (2) use `$( document ).ready()`. See my updated answer for the complete code. Also, see this pull request  -> https://github.com/betseg/betseg.github.io/pull/2

Comment: @JohnSlegers : I accidently merged first PR, but after some rm -rf's, I managed to merge the second one, and that one works. Thank you! (i will remove that file after a while, it was something totally irrelevant from the thing I was trying to do.)

Comment: @JohnSlegers You are the first user I've seen, that been here for a while and have good reps., that added an already given answer to his own post.   ... Are you going to roll back your Note 2. edit or should I delete my answer, as I can't see any good in having the same solution twice?

Comment: @LGSon : I added a non-JQuery version to my answer because I don't want to be that guy who tells people to do something in jQuery when it can be done in vanilla JS with the same amount of code. While there are obvious similarities (there's only so many ways to do a certain thing in JS efficiently), the code I added isn't identical to yours. IMO, there are enough subtle differences between my non-jQuery code and the code in your answer for both answers to stand on their own.

Comment: @LGSon : By the way, do note that I added the vanilla JS code after my answer had already become the "accepted" answer, so it didn't have any impact on the author of the question to prefer my answer to yours.

Comment: @JohnSlegers I disagree, the difference between the two is to little to be valid as different answers, so I deleted mine. I would never add someone else's solution into mine like that, not even if some would say _I'm that guy who tells people to do something in jQuery when it can be done in vanilla JS_ , IMHO very unprofessional, so -1 from me.

Comment: @LGSon : Again, I DID NOT copy your answer. Unlike your version, my "vanilla JS" version was explicitly intended to look like and behave as much as possible like the jQuery-version, using eg. `Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector)).forEach(f)` to mimic the behavior of `$(selector).on('click', f)`.  How is that even remotely the same to what you were doing in your answer?

Comment: @JohnSlegers The OP didn't ask for how to loop the button to which the event handlers were to be attached, s/he asked how to change their attributes, which was the same in both answers.

Comment: @LGSon : That's because `document.querySelector("input[type=text]").setAttribute('name', e.target.value); e.target.form.action = e.target.getAttribute('formaction');` is the ONLY optimal way to do this in vanilla JS, and even here our code isn't 100% identical, as I didn't use a variable for `document.querySelector("input[type=text]")`. Also, my jQuery code does exactly the same thing (only using jQuery-style coding) and already did this BEFORE you updated your version. I might just as well argue that you copied your answer from me because you did the exact same thing, only without jQuery.

Comment: @JohnSlegers Thank you for confirming they were the same, now I have no more comments.

Comment: @LGSon : No, there weren't the same. It's just two lines of code that were *almost* identical, and that's only because those two lines were the right thing to do... which is the same thing I was *already* doing with jQuery before I added a vanilla JS version, and which your answer did NOT include before I added it to mine (you took a very different approach). So, I really, really, really don't understand why you're making such a fuzz about this.